# Android Service not active always

Tags: android, android-service

I use alarm service to start the service forever but this is not a solution and sometime stopped to work too  ... so What is the best way to run a service always like  WhatsApp?

Answer (score 0):

After android oreo google restricted to run service for long time. You need to go with firebase or any persistent notification by using following code

context.startForegroundService(intent); -> you need to put startForeground() code in the onCreate method of the service.